# Sap business one studio system form error object reference not set

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sapb1

I have created a project in SAP Business One Studio with system form.(.xml)  when I open with sap business one studio .xml forms get such an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I found out about the GAC in my research. but I could not find a solution

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have 3 possibilities for solution

1. make sure you are running the visual studio on same platform as your sap client (86/64)
2. make sure both or none of the program are on administrator permission
3. check that the connection string is present (in the command line or as a string)

   sap client must run while you try to run the visual studio code

Hope it helps, it helped me

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps you said but I don't understand the third step. how do i check which connection string ?

Comment: BEFORE STARTING:
//1. Add reference to the "SAP Business One UI API"
//2. Insert the development connection string to the "Command line //argument"

// 1.
//    a. Project->Add Reference...
//    b. select the "SAP Business One UI API 2007" From the COM folder
//
// 2.
//     a. Project->Properties...
//     b. choose Configuration Properties folder (place the arrow on Debugging)
//     c. place the following connection string in the 'Command line arguments' field
// 0030002C0030002C00530041005000420044005F00440061007400650076002C0050004C006F006D0056004900490056
//

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall SAP B1 client and re-install it. It is a common error between SAP and Visual Studio.

Comment: You mentioned in your previous comments that there is a dll problem and gacutil. I didn't find the solution. I tested it on other servers, but I get the same result